# Dell PowerConnect SNMP stack member monitoring

Tags: networking, switch, dell, dell-powerconnect

I am looking to monitor a stack of Dell PowerConnect 6248p switches via SNMP. There is a stack of 3 switches that I want to monitor.

Due to the stack being 1 logical unit it only has 1 IP, so when monitoring via Nagios as long as 1 switch in the stack is still up it reports no problem. If the switches were not stacked and given individual IP's then I could monitor with Nagios no problem.

Is there a way with SNMP to determine if a stack member is online or offline in a stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can find one DELL MIB here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/librenms/librenms/master/mibs/Dell-Vendor-MIB

and it contains a few itens related to stack as "productIdentificationPerUnitTable" . But you will need some trick on monitoring system to check if stack is fully operational.

But traps seems the best way to do. Check it: 
http://www.snmplink.org/cgi-bin/nd/m/Ent/D/Dell%20Computer%20Corporation/Dell/Networking/PowerConnect%20Network%20Switches/![ALL]%20ONM/v3.0.1.15/dell_trap.my